# Making connection of first quantization to second quantization, (quantum field theory)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, second-quantization

In first quantization, a state of system is represented by wavefunction (w.f.) $\phi(x)$ (a representation of a state $|\phi\rangle$ in Hilbert space). The way I understand it is that $|\phi(x)|^2$ gives probability of finding a particle at position $x$. So, $|\phi\rangle$ is a column matrix (written in some basis). Understandable to me!

In second quantization, the many-body state of system is represented by field operators. According to Wikipedia, field operators are given in terms of creation and annihilation operators
$$\Psi = \sum_\nu \psi_\nu \hat{a}_\nu \quad ; \quad \Psi^\dagger = \sum_\nu \psi_\nu^* \hat{a}_\nu^\dagger$$
where $\psi$ is ordinary first quantization w.f. and $\hat{a} (\hat{a}^\dagger$) is annihilation (creation) operator.

I don't understand that how does the field operators represent a state? How can I intuitively think about it? How to relate a field operator representation with physical system? What is physical meaning for a field operator?

Comment: Where did you see the claim that the *state* of a many body system is represented by field operators?

Comment: An operator isn't the same thing as a state. Just think in terms of undergraduate quantum mechanics: does $\hat{x}$ represent the state $|\psi \rangle$?

Comment: @J.Murray so there is no concept of "state of system" in field theory?

Comment: @knzhou actually that is what confuse me. An "operator" is not same as a "state". From undergrad quantum mechanics: a system is represented by a "state"; and an operator is applied on that state to get information from the system.
So, where is that concept of "state" in second quantization?

Comment: I mean, the state is still there, in basically the exact same way. Why don't you think there is a state?

Comment: @knzhou oh. wait. 
so, let's say that in first quantization, we have a state $|\phi\rangle = a_1 |\nu_1\rangle + a_2 |\nu_2\rangle$, where $a_i$ are constants. In second quantization (according to formula given in question) we have $|
\phi\rangle = \Psi^\dagger|0\rangle = [\psi_1 \hat{a_{\nu 1}^\dagger} + \psi_2 \hat{a}_{\nu 2}^\dagger]|0\rangle = \psi_1|\nu_1\rangle +\psi_2|\nu_2\rangle $.
So, when field operators are applied on vacuum state, we get our usual first quantization state. Am I thinking in right direction?

Comment: Think about it like ordinary quantum mechanics. Acting with $\hat{x}$ on the ground state $|0 \rangle$ of a harmonic oscillator doesn't give you the state of the system. The state of the system is just some $|\psi \rangle$. Similarly, in field theory $\Psi^\dagger |0 \rangle$ isn't the state of the system. It's _a_ state, which may or may not be useful to consider.

Comment: Do you understand what outputs are computed in QFT? Fields are technical means for these amplitude computations, but obsessing on their "meaning" will not really tell you much of utility.

Answer (score 1):

Summarising what is being said in the comments and adding some info: the many-body state of a system *can* be represented by field operators *acting* on some state, but it would be incorrect to say that field operators represent a many-body state. If the annihilation and creation operators diagonalize the hamiltonian, then it is convenient to use the basis of Fock states, written in terms of $\hat{a}_\nu$, $\hat{a}^\dagger_\nu$ acting on the ground state $|0\rangle$. The strength of the second quantization formalism is here. It allows to treat many-body states in a much simpler way.

Finally, the field operators do have a physical meaning as it is not hard to show that the field operators destroy/create a particle at point $\boldsymbol{x}$.